# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

So I'm getting this error on my asp.net page and don't really know what to do. Anybody have any ideas? I'm trying to connect to a MYSQL 5.0 server, if that helps anyone.
[image: Error page]

Here's the list of references I have in this project
[image]

Comment: There are many related questions to this kind of problem. Have you tried any solution from those?

Comment: No the answers really don't help me on those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you get your .dll with NuGet ? Or you have referenced it from a local path ? The problem appears to be a mismatch between versions of the dll and the server itself.

Please see the following link: [Version Mismatch MySQL](http://geekswithblogs.net/anirugu/archive/2015/01/16/how-to-fix-mysql-version-mismatch-with-nuget-when-itrsquos.aspx)

Comment: Well, I have published the project and uploaded it to 1and1 and am trying to use their MYSQL 5.0 server.

Comment: All of the references are located inside the bin folder of my project

Comment: If you say that the .dll are located in the .bin folder of your project it is ok. But please check if you are really referencing them from within the .bin folder and that the MySQL dll should have it's property Copy Local = true. You can achieve this by viewing the dll's property or by clicking the referenced .dll and hit F4.

Comment: Copy local is equal to false, changing it now!

Answer (score 0):

You use  Entity Framework 6 assemblies. Read this article http://lvasquez.github.io/2014/11/18/EntityFramework-MySql/
Entity Framework 6 requires MySQL Server 5.1 or above.

**UPDATE**

Check  your mysql dll version in WebConfig, and try to install the version you need. Note Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity install 6.9.6 and Install-Package MySQL.Data.Entities install 6.8.3

When I worked with the Entity and Mysql I used 6.8.3 ver.